# How to get TFS Build demands for running builds

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Im trying to use the TFS 2015 Client API to get the build details of the new builder system.
I already got pretty far,

Using the GetBuildsAsync i get the currently running builds, but not all properties are filled.

```
var buildClient = new BuildHttpClient(new Uri(m_myCollectionUrl, UriKind.Absolute), cred);
Build[] buildsInProgress = (buildClient.GetBuildsAsync(projectName, statusFilter: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildStatus.InProgress)).Result.ToArray();
```

the Build.Demands list is always null even if the build definition has one or more default Demands, also when specifying another one at build queue time, it is not showing up using the API. The list is always null.

I have tried in a few ways now 
buildClient.**GetFullDefinitionsAsync** - results in a **BuildDefinition** where demands = null 
buildClient.**GetDefinitionAsync** - results in a **BuildDefinition** where demands is filled with the default demands from the defintion, but only the ones we defined ourselves, not the system ones.
buildClient.**GetBuildsAsync** - results in a **Build** where demands is null So i still haven't found a call where i can get the Demands that have been used to find that **BuildAgent**. To test above, i am running a test build with 2 "exists" demands and i specify another at queue time, which i cannot find back.

I am not able to find much around this online. What should i do  to get more details on the builds.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the result in `Demands` when you get the details of the build definition instead of a running build?

Comment: I have tried in a few ways now
buildClient.GetFullDefinitionsAsync - results in a BuildDefinition where demands = null
buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync - results in a BuildDefinition where demands is filled with the default demands from the defintion, but only the ones we defined ourselves.
buildClient.GetBuildsAsync - results in a Build where demands is null

So i still haven't found a call where i can get the Demands that have been used to find that BuildAgent.
To test above, i am running a test build with 2 "exists" demands and i specify another at queue time, which i cannot find back.

Comment: Got the same result as you, afraid the value=null is due to the demand is exists instead of equals. Actually there is not any value of it in the web portal.

Answer (score 0):

The demands is a new feature in vNext build system. With using [Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-build-details) to get either a build detail or build definition, there is also not any related default demands info in response json.

Afraid this is due to some default demand is setting **exists**, and the value is null. If you manually add a demand with **equals** something, this will return accordingly value.

[image]

From the response json in rest api of [getting build definition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions), will get something as below:

> "demands": [
>       "agentname -equals test"   ],

Suggest you to use  client API to get the build definition info, if there are equals setting, this will return some value of the demand.

```
  public static DefinitionReference[] GetBuildDefinitions(this BuildHttpClient buildServer, string collectionName)
    {
        var buildDefinitions = buildServer.GetDefinitionsAsync(project: collectionName).Result.ToList();
        return buildDefinitions.ToArray();
    }
```

---

**Update**

Afraid you could not  use Client API to get the default system demands list of the build definition and the agent queue position. It's TFS sever based. It's not able to use a Client API to get TFS sever side info.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean here.
Getting the DefinitionReference doesn't contain much useful info.
No matter what demand i specify, even a demand with equals and a value, im not getting any Demands using the client API in either the Build or BuildDefinition.

Comment: What i also dont seem able to get is the queue position. I now created a Build that is waiting for an available agent, i can see it gets status NotStarted in the Client API, but QueuePosition remains null, while the Web interface is able to tell me that the queue  position is 2. How are we able to retrieve these details, so we can build a list of all builds waiting in the queue

Comment: To Clarify, its not that the Demand.Value is null, its that the Build.Demand list is 0 or null.

Comment: @Nico Afraid you could not  use Client API to get the default system demands of the build definition and the agent queue position. It's TFS sever based. It's not able to use a Client API to get TFS sever side info.

Comment: That's unfortunate, is there also no other way to retrieve this information programmatically ? The TFS Build Overviews provided are just not good enough for our environment.

Comment: @Nico Demands are **asserted automatically** by build steps or manually by you.  If your build includes steps that have demands, they are listed first. It's not able to retrieve this information such as the auto added demands by tfs server in the build definition programmatically for now. Source Link: [Demands](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/options#demands)

Comment: Ok thanks. It seems strange that we cannot access this information. we currently dont have any demands on steps or assign demands.
We simply set demands on the build definition and queue the build.
Suppose we have a list of queued builds, we want to be able to see the demands for each build, that doesnt seem possible.

Comment: @Nico Sorry didn't make it clear. There is no way to configure demands for a specially build task. The demand only could be set on the build definition and during the queue build pop-up  dialog. However, some build  task has their corresponding demands. For example, the Visual Studio Build step demands that `msbuild` and `visualstudio` are installed on the build agent. You could create a test by creating an empty build definition, there should be none demands under the  in the build definition. When you add the Visual  Studio Build step, there will be two demands msbuild VisualStudio automatic

Comment: @Nico So these demands are build system auto added based on different build task, it's also not able to remove/delete these demands. And build agents without those demands will not be pick up in the build agent pool. It's just not able to list this kind of demands, for the demands defined  yourselves, you could get this. And you have also mentioned in the above comment `buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync - results in a BuildDefinition where demands is filled with the default demands from the defintion, but only the ones we defined ourselves.` It's also make sense, build system will hand default.

Comment: i can indeed find the configured ones from the build template, but that doesnt mean those are the same as the build that has been queued.
Some definitions allow some demands to be set/filled on queue time, so getting the value from the template doesnt make sense, as you cannot be sure this value is the one that is used while queing a build. 
I dont mean to update or delete demands, all i want is know from a build in the queue is what a build "Demands" from the agent.